# Save MySQL data in order

Tags: mysql

I am having problem with storing the data in mysql. I want to save the data  in an unordered way inside a database. for eg.

```
Number | Name | Section | Grades |
1      | x    | A       | 80%    |
3      | z    | B       | 72%    |
2      | y    | C       | 55%    |
```

I want to save the data inside the database in such a way that the data is saved according to the number in order. It should be stored in order of number.

I saw the function `GROUP BY` which show the data in an arranged way. But I need to save the data in database file that way. Is there any way by which I can make the data in order inside database file.?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: why do you want to save it in an order. Just order it on the way out and use appropriate indexes.

Comment: How does it matter to you, even if the data is saved in any order?? As, while retrieving the data you can use order by to order the data as you want

Comment: The main db I am working with is supposed to open with some other software and other software is showing in order that the database currently have. This is the reason.

Comment: You can create a view to show that shows the data in the order you want, and access from the other software directly in this view, not on the main table.

Comment: @pokoli Can I arrange the actual data..??

Comment: Why do you care, in which order the data pages are saved in file. Rather, care about retrieval of those data in order using `order by` clause.

Comment: @Tirthajust4u just addapted the answer with a more detailed explanation about views.

Comment: The order of the data returned from a SELECT if no ORDER BY is specified is not strictly defined. It likely will change between storage engines and whether any records have been added / deleted / updated / etc.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the data is save is not relevant to you as you can use the ORDER BY operator to order your select results.

An example query by sorting the data will be:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY name ASC;
```

You can see the full documentation on:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Reading the comments, a view may be usefull for you, so you can access the data in an ordered way from the other software:

```
CREATE VIEW <view_name> AS  SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY name ASC;
```

And the you can access the view with

```
SELECT * from <view_name>
```

and your data will be in the order you defined in the view query.

You can find the full view reference on:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I know about this,my question was to save in order in database in ascending order.. This lets me view the data not arrange the data in actual database..

Answer (score 0):

this one is will going to display in grades format like as,3,2,1 :

```
 SELECT number,name, section, grades FROM tablename ORDER BY grades DESC;
```